# CakePHP 3: Can't add a property to an object stored in a session.

Tags: php, oop, session, cakephp, object

I store an object to a session by doing:

```
$this->request->session()->write('order', $order);
```

In another controller I try to add another property to the same object:

```
$this->request->session()->write('order.client_id', $client->id);
```

But for some reason this overwrites the whole object and I'm left with an object which only has one property, the newly created client_id.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: you sure you're [doing it the right way](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)? I wonder specifically about those parenthesis after session.

Comment: I think that I'm using it correctly. Keep in mind that I'm using CakePHP3.

Comment: Oh my bad, you are right that seems to be the proper way. Did you change anything in the cakephp code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dots are used to indicate nested arrays. This notation is used for all Session component methods wherever a name/key is used.
>
> -- [Interacting with Session data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)

Are you sure your `$order` variable is an array, and not an object?

If `$order` is an object, you have to get the object, change it and put it again in session.

```
$order = $this->request->session()->read('order');
$order->client_id = $client->id;
$this->request->session()->write('order', $order);
```

Comment: $order is an object. Is there a way to add a property to it?

Comment: If this answer is the correct answer for you, you may "check it" so people will know this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to work around this by doing:

```
$order = $this->request->session()->read('order');
$order->client_id = $client->id;
$this->request->session()->write('order', $order);
```